# Как правильно использовать DTO?

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования, архитектура, symfony

Допустим у меня есть такой контроллер:

```
class ItemController
{
     public function getItems(Request $request)
     {
         return $this->itemService->getItems($this->getUser(), $request->get('category_id'));
     }

     public function getItem(int $id, Request $request)
     {
         return $this->itemService->getItem($this->getUser(), $id, $request->get('category_id'));
     }

     public function patchItem(ItemDTO $item, Request $request)
     {
         return $this->itemService->patchItem($this->getUser(), $item, $request->get('category_id'));
     }
}
```

Я хочу убрать передачу кучу параметров(`$categoryId`, `$id`, `$user`)
в методы сервиса и сделать что-то вроде такого:

```
 public function getItem(int $id, Request $request)
 {
     $itemDTO = new ItemDTO($this->getUser(), $id, $request->get('category_id')); //here $title and others is empty
     return $this->itemService->getItem($itemDTO);
 }
```

И новый DTO:

```
class ItemDTO
{
    final public $user;

    final public $id;

    final public $categoryId;

    final public $title;

    //...

    public function __construct($user = null, $id = null, $categoryId = null, $title = null, ...)
    {
       //assign variables
    }
}
```

Это нормальных подход, что в `ItemDTO` останутся пустыми поля `title` все остальные что следуют за ним? Так же еще вопрос, мне понадобятся фильтры типа `pageSize`, `pageNumber` и т.д, стоит ли их размещать в DTO, либо сделать отдельный класс `ItemFilter`?

Answer (score 0):

да, нормально оставлять часть параметров пустыми, но какой смысл будет от этого объекта, если его можно создать вообще без передачи параметров? Т.е. можно получить сущность по ничему?

Насчет фильтрации, можете попробовать пихнуть в этот же DTO и посмотреть что будет, правильного ответа на данный вопрос нет, все зависит от вас.